# UI and unity position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this problem, that I want to be able to click on a "tile" on the screen and then a pop-up menu should be shown just next to the tile. I can click on the tile and then a pop-up menu shows up but not where I want it.

On the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Ra5.png) I've clicked on the top left one.

My code for placing the picture is as following:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TowerMenu : MonoBehaviour 
{
    bool showMenu = false;
    float x;
    float y;
    GUIStyle myStyle;

    public Texture2D[] towers;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(showMenu)
        {
            //Bear tower
            GUI.Button(new Rect(x + 10, y - 25, 50, 50), towers[0]);
            //Seal tower
            GUI.Button(new Rect(x + 10, y + 25, 50, 50), towers[1]);
        }
    }

    public void ShowMenu(Vector2 pos)
    {
        showMenu = true;
        x = pos.x;
        y = pos.y;
    }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: I'm not clear from your picture what represents a "tile" and what represents a "popup." Also, it seems as though you are offsetting the position of your popup by `10` on the X-axis, which might have some bearing on your question.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please do not misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sry, i cant comment because i dont have enough rep, this is a comment to Steven Mills answer and comments to that post.

The first error comes because you are calling WorldToViewportPoint as if it was a static member function which it isnt(Think of if you had 2 Cameras you would have to specify which Camera you want, reading up on what a static member is would be helpful here). What you need to do to fix this is get a reference of your MainCamera and call the function from that instance(best method would probably be with a public variable and dragging the camera on the script in the editor)

The second error occurs because you are trying to give a Vector3 to ShowMenu() which requires a Vector2. The third is probably a product of the compiler trying to fix error 2

This is a logical error because the tiles are GameObjects and thus the transform.position are positions in 3d space. What you actually want is the 2d-pixel-position on the screen of your MainCamera. To get this you need to call [WorldToScreenPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) instead of WorldToViewportPoint. Sadly, as you will notice you will also get a Vector3 here which is not what you want, but you can just take the x and y coordinates as your pixel screen coordinates. the z-coordinate denotes the distance from the camera.

Hope that clears it up a little instead of confusing you ;D

Feel free to ask again, but also try to read the Unity Script Reference and try to understand what is written there and what it means :)

Answer (score 0):

By the look of it, your `ShowMenu` method is receiving a pos of (0,0), which is why the two buttons are placed at what seems to be a position of (10,-25) and (10,25) respectively.

Without seeing the code calling `ShowMenu` I can't be sure what location you're giving, but my guess would be that the tiles belong to a parent object, and you're passing the local position instead of the world position.

If you post the code in which you call `ShowMenu` I may be able to point out any problems.

EDIT:

Based on the information provided in the comments, the problem is that the position needs converting between the world coordinates and screen coordinates:

```
void OnMouseDown()
        {
                if(state == State.water)
                {
                        errorHandler.sendError("You can't click on that");
                }

                if(state == State.ice)
                {
                        towerMenu.ShowMenu(camera.WorldToViewportPoint(this.transform.position));
                }
        }
```

and change the ShowMenu to this:

```
public void ShowMenu(Vector3 pos)
    {
        showMenu = true;
        x = pos.x;
        y = pos.y;
    }
```

Comment: This is the code that is calling the show menu:

http://pastebin.com/Zm99Dfie

The way tiles work is that is have two states, ice and water. When it's water you are not allowed to click on it and when it's ice you can click on it and the menu pops up.
The tiles GO is build up from 3 thing, an empty GO with a collider, and two child's with an ice and water sprite that I can switch between. When I click on the ice tile I get the empty GO's position which for some reason only is from 3 to -3. 

http://i.imgur.com/QCPE6hH.png

Just like you can see up here

Comment: I see how this is gonna work but I'm getting 3 error: http://pastebin.com/nRmC4RWf
I've put them in the link above. I've tried to solve them but can't see how :(

Comment: I've re-editted the answer with the full code. Hopefully this is a little clearer.